# Construct YAML that contains JSON data in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, yaml

I have a file `config.json` that contains some JSON as follows:

```
{  
   "json":{  
      "type":"service",
      "project":"project",
      "key":"key",
      "client":"client"
   },
   "project_id":"1"
}
```

I want to include this JSON data in a YAML file.

YAML will look like this (This is my required output):

```
contexts:
- config:
    json: |
      {
        "type": "service",
        "project": "project",
        "key": "key",
        "client": "client"
      }
    project_id: "1"
  name: cloud
current-context: cloud
```

Here, two keys `json` & `project_id` are coming from `config.json` data.
This JSON data is added as `config` under `contexts`.

The following underlines two information coming from `config.json` data.

```
contexts:
- config:
    json: |
    ----
      {
      }
    project_id: "1"
    ----------
  name: cloud
current-context: cloud
```

How can I do this?

I have tried as below:

```
with open("config.json") as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f)

config_map = {}
for key in config:
    config_map[key] = str(config[key])

context = dict(
    config=config_map,
    name="cloud",
)

data = {
    "contexts": [context],
    "current-context": "cloud",
}
```

But this is not correct.
Can anyone point me to the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to dump the value for key `json` as a literal block style scalar you can use:

```
import sys
from ruamel import yaml

with open("config.json") as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f)

for key in config:
    try:
        int(config[key])
        val = yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString(config[key])
    except TypeError:
        val = yaml.round_trip_dump(
            config[key], default_flow_style=True, width=10, default_style='"')
        val = val.replace('{"', '{\n  "').replace('"}', '"\n}')
        val = yaml.scalarstring.PreservedScalarString(val)
    config[key] = val

context = dict(
    config=config,
    name="cloud",
)

data = {
    "contexts": [context],
    "current-context": "cloud",
}

yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives you **exactly** your required output. You might want to adjust the `try` statement that determines on what gets rendered as a double quoted  scalar, and what as a literal block scalar.

Comment: Under config, value for json key will be string. I mean full json will be in string format.

Comment: I am not concern about Integer/string part actually. Fixed my question to use  `project_id` as string. I actually need embedded JSON in YAML. An output just like I have pointed

Comment: @AerofoilKite I updated the final program to exactly generate your required output.